# fatal error: openssl/base.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, grpc

I'm trying to install P4studio. When I install grpc (use the command `sudo pip install .`), Linux18.04 report a error.The specific error message is as follows:

```
cc1: warning: command line option ‘-std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
    src/boringssl/err_data.c:17:10: fatal error: openssl/base.h: No such file or directory
     #include <openssl/base.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    creating tmp
    creating tmp/tmpvpIqnh
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-gnDdqE/python2.7-2.7.17=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c /tmp/tmpvpIqnh/a.c -o tmp/tmpvpIqnh/a.o
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-m6MRGy-build/setup.py", line 353, in <module>
        cmdclass=COMMAND_CLASS,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 162, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 601, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 128, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 84, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
        _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/tmp/pip-m6MRGy-build/src/python/grpcio/commands.py", line 277, in build_extensions
        "Failed `build_ext` step:\n{}".format(formatted_exception))
```

Is there some any way to address it?
Thanks!

Comment: Try `sudo apt install libssl-dev` to install ssl development libraries.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I have tried it, but it didn't work . The error still exists.

Comment: "Didn't work" doesn't tell us if it couldn't install the package, or did install the package but didn't fix the Python module's compilation.

Comment: "Linux18.04" is not well-defined. I'm guessing that's the Ubuntu version number.

Comment: If it's the latter, I'd want to look at exactly which version of OpenSSL headers you installed, and exactly which version the module you're trying to build is advertised to work with.

Comment: "Didn't work" means it installed the package but didn't fix the Python module's compilation. "Linux18.04"  is the Ubuntu version number. The  version of OpenSSL is 1.1.1

Comment: If you use `dpkg -L libssl-dev` to look at the contents of the package you installed, does it actually contain a file `openssl/base.h`?